# How to avoid old style outer join (+) in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've wrote HQL query like this:

```
SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.b where ...
```

Hibernate generate sql query like this:

```
SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.b where a.b_id = b.id(+)
```

But when I write something like this:

```
SELECT a FROM where a.b.id > 5
```

It generate SQL:

```
SELECT a.* FROM A b cross join B b where b.id > 5
```

So when I combine this approaches I recieve Oracle ERROR:

```
SQL Error: 25156, SQLState: 99999
ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins
```

So is there way to say to Hibernate that I want receive only one type of queries (old style or new) ?

**UPDATE:**
By combining I mean HQL query like this:

```
SELECT alarm FROM Alarm as a LEFT JOIN alarm.madeBy as user where user.name = 'George' and a.source.name = 'UFO'
```

So here I specify that **Alarm** should be connected with **User** with LEFT JOIN, and not specify how connect **Alarm** with **Source**, so Hibernate will connect it with Cross Join.

And SQL Query will be like this:

```
FROM Alarms a, Users u cross join Sources s where a.user_id = u.user_id(+) and a.source_id = s.source_id and u.name = 'George' and s.name = 'UFO'
```

For more understanding I will add small example of Alarm Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'Alarms')
public class Alarm {
   @Id
   private BigDecimial id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User madeBy;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "source_id")
   private Source source;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by combining the approaches?

Comment: Please show some code for the "combined" approach.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the solving of this problem is set hibernate's Dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you try to obtain SQL query below by using HQL.

```
SELECT a.* FROM A ,B where a.b_id = b.id(+) and b.id > 5
```

Firstly, you should never use code like that **a.b.XX** at your HQL.

the sample code is

```
SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.b where b.id is null or (b.id is not null and b.id > 5)
```

then hibernate genarates a SQL query that does not cause an exception.