# LEFT Join not Working with JPA, CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, predicate

I have two tables with `one-to-many` association:

```
Student            Subject
------------     ----------------------
ID|name|age      ID | Student_FK | name
------------     ----------------------
```

A Student can have any number of subjects associated with him. (no subjects too). Now I want to get all students with

> subject.name = 'PHYSICS' **OR** no subject at all (NULL)

I am using QueryBuilder and predicates to generate the query, following is the code snippet.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = mEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(mEntityClass);
Root root = cq.from(mEntityClass);
cq.select(root);
List<String> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
subjectList.add("PHYSICS");
Join  subjectJoin= root.join("subjects", JoinType.LEFT);
Predicate predicate1 = subjectJoin.get("name").in(subjectList);
Predicate predicate2 = subjectJoin.get("name").isNull();
Predicate predicate = cb.or(predicate1,predicate2);
predicates.add(predicate);
cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
```

When I do a `mEntityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList()`. I get Error as -

> old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins

So my question is -

1. How to get a LEFT join using CritariaQuery ?
2. Is there some other way to get all Students list (both with subjects/ without Subject) ?

Comment: For starters it seems you are using an invalid Oracle/Hibernate dialect combination. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674565/how-to-avoid-old-style-outer-join-in-hibernate). Then the `IN` predicate seems wrong too: maybe use a `List<String>`, add the name of the subject and do what you do now.

Comment: Hey Nikos, thanks for pointing it out. But my concern is that changing the config will effect other parts of Codebase too. is there any other way to achieve it, without changing the config.?

Comment: I do not know (and I do not think it is possible, except perhaps native queries).

Comment: One of your predicates is on "team" but none of your columns is named "team."

Comment: Sorry That was a typo